# React App, How do you map and sort titles in an Api Array in alphabetical order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, frontend

Hi I'm trying to map and sort titles from an API in React in alphabetical order. I keep getting .sort() is not a function and I don't know where to sort my array. I would love some help!!

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect}from 'react';
import fetchMovies from '../../services/Movie-api';

export default function Movies(){
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState("")

    async function getMovies(){
        const movieData = await fetchMovies()

        console.log(movieData)
        setMovies(movieData.data.data)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getMovies()
    },[])

    return ( 
        <>
            {movies ? (
                <div>
                    <div>{movies.map((m,idx) => {
                        return <div key={idx}>{m.title}</div>
                    })}  
                    </div>
                </div>
            ):( "loading...")}
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: are you sure that data is an array and not String? if yes sort should be work.

Comment: You're trying to `map` over a string (your initial state). Change it to `useState([])`. Add in a condition that shows something else if the length of the array is 0: eg `if (!movies.length) return <div />`.

Comment: As @Andy said, You should add empty `[]` bracket in useState and use sort before setting it into state. `movieData.data.data.sort(function (a, b) {  return a.value - b.value; });`

Comment: So I added into usestate([]) and put in the sort function but my array still hasn't been sorted. It's not doing anything to it right now :/

Comment: ```export default function Movies(){

const [movies, setMovies] = useState([])

async function getMovies(){
    const movieData = await fetchMovies()

    console.log(movieData)
    setMovies(movieData.data.data.sort((a,b) => a - b))
}```

Answer (score 0):

got it working with this!

```
setMovies(movieData.data.data.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title)))
```